# How to get the specific data from postgresql database when an user logs in after admin assigning the data using codeigniter?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I'm making project where i have 1 admin & 10-15 users.

For each user, I want to only show to them the cases specifically assigned to them to load on their dashboard when admin assigns them. cases that was not assigned to them will not be listed on their dashboard.

Admin can successfully assign case_id to a table

Here is the  case_assignment table which has case_id (which the admin assigns), username (to whom the case assigned), assigned date.

similarly users table there is username,password,level(admin is 1 and all other user are 2),email

if the admin had assigned the case (case_id will be present) to particular username in case_assignment table, then, when user logins, he should be  able to see  all the data (tables) related to that particular case_id.
here are screenshot:

Admin page: https://prnt.sc/novscc --> this how the datatable will be displayed for admin.. he will be having all case data. when he assigns case to user. user should receive only that case.

User page: https://prnt.sc/novtnr -> this is how i want user datatable to be displayed when admin assigns a case.

Here is the database case_assigment table screen shot : https://prnt.sc/novtze (here only case_id & username to whom admin wants to assigns will be there).

**Here is the view, user.php**

```
<table id="table" class="table table-striped table-bordered display nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%" "style="width: 650px;">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Case ID</th>
                    <th>Case Name</th>
                    <th>Firm Name</th>
                    <th>Case Overview</th>
                    <th>Priority</th>
                    <th>Received Date</th>
                    <th>Expected Delivery Date</th>
                    <th>Service Status</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        <tbody>
                <?php

                        if($result){
                           foreach ($result as $results) {                                
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $results->case_id; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $results->case_name; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $results->firm_name; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $results->case_description; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $results->priority; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $results->received_date; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $results->expected_delivery_date; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $results->service_status; ?></td>
                </tr> 
    <?php
            }
        }
    ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

**Here is my Controller (employee.php)**

```
    public function index()
  {   
      $this->load->helper('url');
      $this->session->userdata('username');
      $data['result'] = $this->HomeModel->get_employee($case_id);
      $this->load->view('case/user',$data);
      //print_r($data);
      //die;
  }
```

**Here is my model (HomeModel.php)**

```
public function get_employee($case_id)
    {
        $this->session->userdata('username');
        $this->db->select('case_main.case_id,
                       case_main.case_name,
                       case_main.firm_name,
                       case_overview.case_description,
                       case_priority.priority,
                       service_delivery_dates.received_date, 
                       service_delivery_dates.expected_delivery_date,  
                       service_delivery_dates.service_status');
      $this->db->from('case_tracker.case_assignment');
      $this->db->join('case_tracker.case_main', 'case_tracker.case_assignment.case_id=case_tracker.case_main.case_id');
      $this->db->join('case_tracker.case_overview', 'case_tracker.case_main.case_id = case_tracker.case_overview.case_id','left');
      $this->db->join('case_tracker.case_priority', 'case_tracker.case_overview.case_id = case_tracker.case_priority.case_id' , 'left');
      $this->db->join('case_tracker.service_delivery_dates', 'case_tracker.case_priority.case_id = case_tracker.service_delivery_dates.case_id' , 'left');
      $this->db->where('case_assignment_case_id', $case_id);
      $data = $this->db->get();    
      return $data->result();
  }
```

Note:- Here case_main, case_overview, case_priority, service_delivery_dates are the different tables in databases and case_tracker is my schema name.

I dont know what to write in controller to fetch the case_id that the admin assigns and when user logs in he/she should be able to see all the data o the particular case_id

Expected result:-
Admin page: https://prnt.sc/novscc --> this how the datatable will be displayed for admin.. he will be having all case data. when he assigns case to user. user should receive only that case.

User page: https://prnt.sc/novtnr -> this is how i want user datatable to be displayed when admin assigns a case.

Here is the database case_assigment table screen shot : https://prnt.sc/novtze (here only case_id & username to whom admin wants to assigns will be there).

For each user, I want to only show to them the cases specifically assigned to them to load on their dashboard when admin assigns them. cases that was not assigned to them will not be listed on their dashboard.

if the admin had assigned the case (case_id will be present) to particular username, then, when user logins, he should be  able to see that all the data (tables) related to that particular case_id.

Please help me, im new and learning programming language.

Comment: these two concepts seem conflicting: "For each user, I want to only show to them the *cases* specifically assigned to them" vs "when user logins, he should be able to see that all the data (tables) related to that particular case_id *[single case?]*" which is it? your code seems to suggest the latter. also, does the above query work? or does it fail? because there seems to be some weird things.

Comment: @Alex Let me make it clear, admin assigns the case_id (which will then comes to  case_assignment table, once he assigns) and when user login all the table having same case_id should be present in dashboard. For example: if admin assigns case_id=A00010. This case_id (A00010) will be present in case_assignment table which has following columns(case_id, username, assigned_on). when user logins he should be able to see data having case_id=A100010 from all tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thnx @Alex for the help,

Here is the Result which i was looking for:

```
Controller:

     public function index()
    { 
       $data['result'] = $this->HomeModel->get_employee_case();
       $this->load->view('case/user');
    /*
       print_r($data);
       die; */
    }

Model:

    function get_employee_case()
      {
        $this->db->select('case_assignment.case_id,
                           case_main.case_name,
                           case_main.firm_name,
                           case_overview.case_description,
                           case_priority.priority,
                           service_delivery_dates.received_date, 
                           service_delivery_dates.expected_delivery_date,  
                           service_delivery_dates.service_status');
        $this->db->from('case_tracker.case_assignment');
        $this->db->join('case_tracker.case_main', 'case_tracker.case_assignment.case_id=case_tracker.case_main.case_id', 'left');
        $this->db->join('case_tracker.case_overview', 'case_tracker.case_main.case_id=case_tracker.case_overview.case_id', 'left');
        $this->db->join('case_tracker.type_of_services', 'case_tracker.case_overview.case_id = case_tracker.type_of_services.case_id', 'left');
        $this->db->join('case_tracker.specific_instructions', 'case_tracker.type_of_services.case_id = case_tracker.specific_instructions.case_id' , 'left');
        $this->db->join('case_tracker.case_priority', 'case_tracker.specific_instructions.case_id = case_tracker.case_priority.case_id' , 'left');
        $this->db->join('case_tracker.service_delivery_dates', 'case_tracker.case_priority.case_id = case_tracker.service_delivery_dates.case_id' , 'left');
        $this->db->where('case_assignment.username', $this->session->userdata('username'));
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment I assume that one employee is assigned to one case. Thus:

```
function get_employee_case() {
    $this->db->select('case_id');
    $this->db->where('username', $this->session->userdata('username'));
    $q = $this->db->get('case_assignment');
    if ($q->num_rows() == 1) {
        return $q->row()->case_id;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Controller:

```
$case_id = $this->HomeModel->get_employee_case();
if (!is_null($case_id)) {
    $data['result'] = $this->HomeModel->get_employee($case_id);
} else {
    $data['result'] = null;
}
```

View:

```
if (is_null($result)) {
    echo 'no case assigned';
} else {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thnx for helping but i  want even data from table row having case_id like this https://prnt.sc/notfqk (attached screenshot)

Comment: Expected result:- Admin page: https://prnt.sc/novscc --> this how the datatable will be displayed for admin.. he will be having all case data. when he assigns case to user. user should receive only that case.

User page: https://prnt.sc/novtnr -> this is how i want user datatable to be displayed when admin assigns a case.

Here is the database case_assigment table screen shot : https://prnt.sc/novtze (here only case_id & username to whom admin wants to assigns will be there)

Comment: i dont understand the problem. your screenshot in the first comment has 2 rows, whereas "how i want user datatable" has 1. i'm not getting a clear answer here. everything you post seems conflicting to me. what is the above code outputting?

Comment: hi alex, thnx for your help, i changed bit of ur code and now i am getting the result which i wanted :)

Comment: i suggest you post your answer; maybe it will help someone else! in any case, an upvote would be appreciated if my answer in some way helped.

Answer (score -1):

You have to first select the all caes assigned to user

```
select * from cases where user_id=2
```

fetch all cases in loop

and then fetch data for each case